# AWS Cognito not sending confirmation code email

Tags: flutter, amazon-cognito

I'm currently trying to implement the `forget password` feature using `AWS Cognito` using `amazon_cognito_identity_dart_2 1.0.3`, on a console it shows that a confirmation code is being sent to the email that I have entered but I'm not receiving anything on the email. 
I wonder if the problem is with my code or on the AWS side configurations?

Here is the email confirmation log on console:
`Code sent to {"CodeDeliveryDetails":{"AttributeName":"email","DeliveryMedium":"EMAIL","Destination":"c***@g***.com"}}`

Below is the code that I have written:

```
Future<bool> resetPassword(String email) async {

   final cognitoUser = new CognitoUser(email, userPool);

   var data;
   try {
     data = await cognitoUser.forgotPassword();
   } catch (e) {
     print(e);
     return Future.error(getError(e));
   }
   print('Code sent to ${json.encode(data)}');
   return true;
 }
```

Comment: Please give more information about what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me, I'm using this package "amazon_cognito_identity_dart_2 1.0.3" for flutter web to reset the password but I'm not getting any response on my emails this is my printing statement on a console. "Code sent to {"CodeDeliveryDetails":{"AttributeName":"email","DeliveryMedium":"EMAIL","Destination":"c***@g***.com"}}
"

Comment: Any update on this?

Comment: Yes, I found out I was using username to get verification code instead of email. Everything is sorted thanks.